# Is it possible to delete/disable the standard field wordpress creates for every page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

As the title says, wordpress creates a field for each page by default, and i would like to disable this and replace it with advanced custom fields. but i didnt find anything in the wordpress settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ACF you have the option of pretty much hiding every default field on a post/page edit screen. It's in the "Hide on screen" section when you are editing your ACF fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete the default settings. Rather you can hide them through the screen options. Leaving the fields blank is what you are looking for.

Leave all the defaults fields blank, hide them and input your data in the custom fields you created.
I wonder if that was what you are looking for.